# Facebook graph API 803 error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Looking for some help forcing Facebook to refresh my open graph meta when a link to a website is shared.

Looking in the docs it says this endpoint should do it

`/?id={object-instance-id or object-url}&scrape=true`

Testing that in the Graph API Explorer with my URL like this

`?id={http://www.portfolio.innofydesign.com/ogimage/index.php}&scrape=true` is giving me an 803 error

```
{

  "error": {

`"message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist:` {http://www.portfolio.innofydesign.com/ogimage/index.php}",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 803,
"fbtrace_id": "D2jH8zJ8kjZ"


 }

}
```

The code on the page looks like this

```
<?php

// Pass session data over.

session_start();



// Include the required dependencies.

require_once( 'facebook-php-sdk-v5/autoload.php' );

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([

  'app_id' => '{app-id}',

  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',

  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',

]);



$titles = array('title1', 'title2', 'title3');

$images = array('http://portfolio.innofydesign.com/ogimage/1.jpg', 'http://portfolio.innofydesign.com/ogimage/2.jpg', 'http://portfolio.innofydesign.com/ogimage/3.jpg');

$descriptions = array('description1', 'description2', 'description3');

?>

<meta property="og:url" content="http://portfolio.innofydesign.com/ogimage/" />

<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $titles[array_rand($titles)]; ?>" />

<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $images[array_rand($images)]; ?>" />

<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $descriptions[array_rand($descriptions)]; ?>"/>

<meta property="og:image:width" content="500" />

<meta property="og:image:height" content="500" />

<title><?php echo $titles[array_rand($titles)]; ?></title>
```

I don't need the page to do anything, it's a blank page that just randomizes a list of available titles, images and descriptions, that part works, it just doesn't update the meta on Facebook.

Comment: The `{...}` are meant to signify that you need to insert a value at this position - but without the actual `{` and `}` around it ...

Comment: And FYI, permanently changing the title won’t work; after the object has received a certain amount of likes/shares, Facebook will “freeze” the title, and not allow changes to it any more.

Comment: @CBroe, thanks for that, i feel a total noob lol, i don't work with API's etc and this just stared out as an experiment which i now want to finish.

How would i go about implementing this on my page so that FB re scrapes the URL every time?

Thanks for the heads up on the shares, does this also effect description and image?

Answer (score -1):

Facebook Events and our other plugins. I can help troubleshoot this with you.

It looks like a username has not been setup for this page and alias you are trying is not working, because it is not valid.

I used just the id instead:

```
1489159701297780
```

And it worked for me.